# Placing texts below three circles using html and css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can i place text below three circles with responsive design in a one div. Sample image below.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should be a good starting point.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle-content">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <p>Circle One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-content">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <p>Circle Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-content">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <p>Circle Three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.circle-content {
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.circle {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
    padding-bottom:60%;
    border-radius:60%;
    border:15px solid #333;
}
.circle-content p {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#666;
}
```